# How to correctly configure xdebug.file_link_format?

Tags: php, textmate, xdebug

I want error messages outputed by xdebug to show up as links in the browser so I can open them quickly using TextMate.

I added the following line to my php.ini file, restarted apache and added a few syntax errors to one of my php scripts but the file name is not showing up as a link. Xdebug is otherwise working fine on my system.

```
xdebug.file_link_format="txmt://open/?url=file://%f&line=%l"
```

Are there additional configurations that I need to set up to make this work?

**Edit:** Here are all the xdebug related configuration settings in my php.ini:

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.file_link_format="txmt://open/?url=file://%f&line=%l"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am running snow leopard with xdebug 2.1.0RC1 and can click errors as links that take me to the correct line in textmate so it is possible to have this working.

Comment: A few days after posting this question I tried with Xdebug 2.1.0beta3 and It didn't work either. 2.1.0RC1 did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

i found solution:
so just replace the xdebug wich comes with MAMP with the lastest one frome here

http://code.activestate.com/komodo/remotedebugging/

then move the link part above the extension part
like

[xdebug]
xdebug.file_link_format="txmt://open?url=file://%f&line=%1"
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"

;xdebug.remote_enable=1
;xdebug.remote_host=localhost
;xdebug.remote_port=9000
;xdebug.remote_autostart=1

than happy happy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is unrelated, but since this question is the top result on most of my Google searches, I figured it may be helpful for someone else.

I put together this quick tutorial on getting `xdebug.file_link_format` to work with Netbeans on Windows. You could easily modify the `.bat` file for any IDE, however.

[`xdebug.file_link_format` for Netbeans on Windows](https://gist.github.com/2065503)